# Dataset from Nested xml in c#

Tags: asp.net

I have an xml output from a webservice which is a nested xml. I have to convert it to a dataset in c#. How can I do it?

Anoop George Thomas

Comment: Use DataSet.ReadXML() method to read the xml file or string.. into the dataset....

Answer (score 0):

check [Linq to XML nested query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495384/linq-to-xml-nested-query) Anoob

And [Load nested XML into dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759243/load-nested-xml-into-dataset)

Answer (score 0):

To fill a DataSet with data from XML, use the ReadXml method of the DataSet object.